# Unable to pyenv install python version on macOS Ventura 13.5

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pyenv

I am trying to install a python version using `pyenv`, e.g.

```
pyenv install 3.11.4
```

but I am always getting this message

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.11.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.4/Python-3.11.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.11.4...
python-build: use tcl-tk from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 13.5 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/kv/l0jzxgbj1kggff_kd35bfzkw0000gn/T/python-build.20230728132126.31601
Results logged to /var/folders/kv/l0jzxgbj1kggff_kd35bfzkw0000gn/T/python-build.20230728132126.31601.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/kv/l0jzxgbj1kggff_kd35bfzkw0000gn/T/python-build.20230728132126.31601/Python-3.11.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

- macOS Ventura 13.5
- CommandLineTools version: 14.3.1.0.1.1683849156

I found and tried [this](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2143) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169855/homebrew-pyenv-cant-install-python-3-8-3-despite-i-already-have-it-installe) but both did not work for me. I am still getting the same error.

Can someone assist me with this?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No, on the laptop I had this problem on I haven't resolved this unfortunately.